# Speeding up slow update query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to update a field based on another table's field using a join:

```
UPDATE transactions
JOIN products ON products.link = transactions.product_id 
SET transactions.user_id = products.user_id
WHERE transactions.user_id != products.user_id
```

However, this is taking a very long time (over 15 minutes). Products has 10K rows, transactions has about 90K rows. Is there anyway I can optimize my query?

Transactions table:

```
id              int(11)
transaction_id  varchar(255)
user_id         int(11)
product_id      varchar(50)
```

Products table:

```
id      int(11)
user_id int(11)
link    varchar(45)
```

Comment: joining on two varchar fields of different sizes requires complete table scans for each update. Is there no other way to join the tables?

Comment: @DavidColwell Unfortunately no other ways to join. I feared it might be to do with that. I can and will change the join field to use an INT in future. But I need to perform this update first. Is the query on its own fine?

Comment: I would have trouble duplicating these results, but try @Mari's approach... might help...

In future, look at it this way. If the transaction already has a UserID, and a transaction has a Product, the Product doesnt need a UserID (unless it makes sense for the product to have a user ID, as in it is the user who created the product originally)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if this sql can help. Can you try?

```
update transactions as T1   
 inner join ( select T2.id , P.user_id
              from transactions as T2, projects as P
              where T2.product_id = P.link
                and T2.user_id != P.user_id
             ) as T3 on T1.id = T3.id
set T1.user_id = t3.user_id
```

Comment: I tested this uisng a `SELECT` and it seems to return the right number of rows but it takes a long time. Also change `projects` to `products`. I think all queries will be slow due to my table design.

Comment: I overlooked this too quickly. I tested your query again and it run within 5 minutes! I've changed this to the correct answer. But I will still be implementing Davids suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues i see here

1. The Products table and the Transactions table are linked via Varchar fields of different sizes. This forces the query optimizer to table scan both (assuming neither are indexed)
2. The products table and transactions table both have user_id on them. Can these ID's be different? If not, perhaps this is data duplication

To make your query faster:

1. Link the tables on the Identity column (i.e. the Transactions table contains a column called product_id int(11) which references the id column in the products table. This will allow you to do extremely fast joins

Comment: I will select this as the correct answer as to really speed up this query and future queries, I need to correct my table design.

Comment: Either way, with tables under 100,000 rows, i would expect results within seconds (max 10 or so) as a guideline

Answer (score 0):

Please try this, Instead of NOT EQUAL you can do a trick with LEFT OUTER JOIN

```
UPDATE transactions
LEFT OUTER JOIN products ON products.link = transactions.product_id AND 
transactions.user_id = products.user_id
SET transactions.user_id = products.user_id
WHERE products.user_id IS NULL AND transactions.product_id IS NULL
```

Comment: This query isn't the same as mine. It returns an empty result, if you just perform a select.

Comment: I tried the latest version and turning it into a select returns 0 results. It should return about 1K rows. Version two of your query returned results but I need to compare it with my original query.

Answer (score 0):

Create two indices, one on products.link and the other on transactions.product_id.

And consider adding the user_id as an included field in each index (if that is supported in mysql; I mostly do SQL Server programming).

Comment: perhaps consider creating a unique index on the products table. If there is duplicates in the product_link field, this will completely bork up the entire process